# Prime number loop stop at first found number

Tags: php

Hello i would like the loop below to generate a random prime number below 1000. But only generate 1 with the variable $i and the variable $finish should allow the while loop to stop after the first prime number is found and if the number is not prime it should generate a new $i variable randomly and check if its a prime number again until the first prime number is found.

```
<html>
  <body>
  <?php
    $finish="a";
    while($finish = "a") {
      $i = (mt_rand(0,999));
      $counter = 0; 
      for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) { //all divisible factors
        if($i % $j == 0) { 
          $counter++;
        }

        //prime requires 2 rules ( divisible by 1 and divisible by itself)
        if($counter == 2){
          print $i." is Prime <br/>";
          $finish = "b";
        }  
      }
  }
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

how can i modify this so that it will stop the code after the first prime number below 1000 is found?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how can i modify this so that it will stop the code after the first prime number below 1000 is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `$finish="a"` - you are assigning the string `a` (which is *truthy*) to `$finish`. So this loop will run forever (as the condition  is always true).

You are setting flags as string and ints while boolean here should suffice. In addition to that, once a divisor `>= 2` is found you can stop the `for()` loop. If you introduce a helper function it becomes even more readable.

```
function isPrime($number) {
    $max = $number;
    for ($i=2; $i < $max; $i++) {
        if ($number % $i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

do {
    $i = mt_rand(100, 9999);
} while ( ! isPrime($i) );

var_dump($i);
```

[See it work here.](http://codepad.org/PHhJVR8k) I'm not too sure but `sqrt($number)` should suffice as `$max` and make the loop shorter -> the script faster.

Comment: how do i add the sqrt($number) to the code below? <html>
<body>
<?php




 $i = (mt_rand(0,999));

          $counter = 0; 
          for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){ //all divisible factors


                if($i % $j==0){ 

                      $counter++;
                }


        //prime requires 2 rules ( divisible by 1 and divisible by itself)
  
    }
echo $i;

?>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

To break out of your 2 loops when the condition is matched, you can use [`break 2`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php):

```
if($counter == 2){
  print $i." is Prime <br/>";
  $finish = "b";
  break 2;
}
```